# regex_match throwing runtime exeception

Tags: c++, regex, exception

```
#include`<iostream>`
#include `<string>`
#include `<regex>`


using namespace std;



int main ()
{

try{



  std::regex re("(http|https)://(\\w+\\.)*(\\w*)/([\\w\\d]+/{0,1})+");
  if (std::regex_match ("http://www.google.com", re))
    {
    std::cout << "valid URL \n";
    }

  else 
    {
    std::cout << "invalid URL \n";
    }
}

 catch(std::regex_error& e)
{

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_brack)
      std::cerr << "Problem with brackets--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_collate)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_collate--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_ctype)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_ctype--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_escape)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_escape--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_backref)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_backref--"<<e.code()<<"\n";


if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_paren)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_paren--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_brace)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_brace--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_badbrace)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_badbrace--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_range)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_range--"<<e.code()<<"\n";

if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_space)
      std::cerr << "Problem error_space--"<<e.code()<<"\n";




}

 std::cout << std::endl;






 return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with the above code ?

I compiled it with `g++  -std=gnu++0x  testURL.cpp`

It compiled well, but when I try to execute with `./a.out`

It throws exception related to regex escape sequences.

What I should correct to o/p valid url

There is some problem with escape sequences in regex?

How we can resolve?

Comment: A good regex for this kind of stuff: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: I got the regular general regular expressions for URL but ,can anybody provide regex specific to c++

Comment: It'd be a good idea to post the actual error message that you got.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this regex:

```
std::regex re("(http|https)://(\\w+\.)*(\\w*)/([\\w\\d]+/?)+");
```

Comment: tried "(http|https)://(\\w+\\.)*(\\w*)/([\\w\\d]+/?)+"         got exception as Problem error_escape--2

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on ideone.com and provide me a link.

Comment: the link is http://ideone.com/WCeCPz  I compiled it  with  command g++ -std=c++0x testty.cpp

Comment: tried this also  std::regex re("(http|https)://(\\w+\\.)*(\\w*)/([\\w\\d]+/?)+");

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting quite a few compilation errors on your ideone link, I  will see if I can fix it.

Comment: don't refer to the errors at ideone copy the program on your system then compile it .I would be thankful if you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, forget about using `std::regex` with gcc; while some regex functions compile, they do not work.

Running your program with clang/libc++ or when using gcc but changing it from `std::regex` to `boost::regex`, I get "`Invalid URL`" output, and the reason for that is that neither the forward slash in your regex nor the part after it (`/([\\w\\d]+/{0,1})+`) appear in the string you're matching.